# Design a selection program using C

Tags: c

## Brief Description

I am currently writing a program that allows users to select via arrow keys, when done selecting, hit 'enter', it then proceeds to the next question etc.

I have done the selection process using the code below :

```
int first_selection(int i){
    while (ch != 0xD)
        {
        ch = _getch ();
        if (ch == 0 || ch == 224)
            {
                switch (_getch ())
                    {
                        case 75:
                        system("cls");
                        left_option();
                        i=1;
                        break;

                        case 77:
                        system("cls");
                        right_option();
                        i=0;
                        break;

                    }
            }
        }
 return i;
}
```

but this only works for one selection, when I write the second question below the first one, it will skip the second question like this :

```
first_selection();
printf("%d",i);
second_selection();
printf("%d",j);
```

I've tried nested while loop but using this will only allow me to press right or left arrow key once, then it will automatically skip to the second question due to getch.

I was wondering if someone can tell me how to design such selection program...

---

### Desired Results

After three selections, it will then output strings according to the user's selection.

Ex:

> Input
>
> 1. User selects left option in the first question
> 2. User selects right option in second question
> 3. User selects right option in third question

---

> Ouput
>
> Left
>
> Right
>
> Right

---

#### Full Code

```
void firstR_option(void);
void firstR_option(void);
void secondL_option(void);
void secondR_option(void);

int ch,i,j;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
firstL_selection();
first_selection();
second_selection();
printf("%d%d",i,j);

return 0;
}


void firstL_option(void){
    printf("LEFT\n");
}


void firstR_option(void){
printf("RIGHT\n");
}

void secondL_option(void){
printf("LEFT\n");
}

void secondR_bread(void){
printf("RIGHT\n");
}

int first_selection(int i){
    while (ch != 0xD)
        {
        ch = _getch ();
        if (ch == 0 || ch == 224)
            {
             switch (_getch ())
                    {
                        case 75:
                        system("cls");
                        firstL_option();
                        i=1;
                        break;

                        case 77:
                        system("cls");
                        firstR_option();
                        i=0;
                        break;

                    }
            }
        }
return i;
}

int second_selection(int j){
    while (ch != 0xD)
        {
        ch = _getch ();
        if (ch == 0 || ch == 224)
            {
                switch (_getch ())
                    {
                        case 75:
                        system("cls");
                        secondL_option();
                        j=1;
                        break;

                        case 77:
                        system("cls");
                        secondR_option();
                        j=0;
                        break;

                    }
            }
        }
 return j;
}
```

Comment: the output stream `stdout` is buffered.  To have any output from a call to `printf()` immediately display on the screen, the `stdout` buffer must be flushed.   this can be performed via several different methods 1) append a '\n' character to the end of the format string. 2) call `fflush( stdout );` 3) perform an input function. 4) the buffer overflows 5) the program ends.

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem.  Otherwise we (probably) will not be able to help you.

Comment: Presumably, this is on Windows.  The `_getch()` is not a standard function, though the Curses library has a `getch()` and there are also functions in `<conio.h>` on Windows that are similar.  You need to clarify the context, and preferably provide an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Note that you don't show `second_selection()`, but it is not clear that the problem is in `first_selection()`.  I'd worry about the general use of `system("cls")`, but that probably isn't related to your current problem.

Comment: @user3629249 I have pasted the full code, thanks for helping

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so far I have no troubles using getch and system("cls")

Comment: I didn't say it would cause problems; it probably won't. But if you moved from Windows to Unix, you'd have to use the correct libraries to get `getch()`, and do the necessary setup and tear down before calling it, etc. And the primary concerns with `system("cls")` are (a) `cls` isn't standard on my machine (a Mac running macOS High Sierra), and (b) running a program to clear the screen is fairly heavy duty when sending an appropriate character sequence from within the program would do the job. The difficulty is 'appropriate character sequence'; there are ramifications, and more ramifications.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I use mac with high sierra too ! Normally I would code in sublime text, but if the code requires libraries exclusive to windows then I would open VMware and connect into my school's cloud computer. I find it quite convenient this way such that  I could switch OS just with a four-finger swipe, files could be simultaneously though google drive desktop app.

Comment: Immediate questions include: (1) what is `left_bread()`? (2) Why not `int main(void)` since the arguments are unused? (3) Why global variables `i` and `j` — that's pretty nasty, especially since the `first_selection()` and `second_selection()` functions return the value, even though you ignore it? (3a) Come to that, why global variable `ch`?  (4) What input is this supposed to take; what output are you supposed to get; what output do you get? (5) What headers are included; which libraries are used for linking?  (6) Is this running on Windows or on a Mac running High Sierra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not debug your code but I believe the reason why it skips the second question is that there is still something left in stdin and you need to somehow discard that.

Something like this will do the trick:

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

The other important thing is arrow keys are special characters and the way you get those values depend on the OS and compiler you have. I am also using macOS Sierra (with gcc) and I had to figure out what characters I get when I press an arrow key with simple getchar() followed by printf() functions.

So for the left arrow key for example, I get: ESC, [, and 'C'.

Then I set-up my function based on that little experiment I did.

Lastly, you can use an array for the answers. This way it is easier to use loops.

Here is the full code (I left some of the error-checking to you):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define UP    65  // A
#define DOWN  66  // B
#define LEFT  68  // C
#define RIGHT 67  // D

int getUserInput()
{
  int c = getchar();
  int retVal = 0;

  if (c == 27)  // ESC
  {
    c = getchar();
    if (c == 91) // [
    {
      c = getchar();
      if (c == UP || c == DOWN || c == LEFT || c == RIGHT)
      {
        retVal = c;
      }
    }
  }
  // Discard what is left in stdin
  while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
  return retVal;
}

void printSelection(int selection)
{
  switch (selection)
  {
    case 65:
      printf("You pressed the UP KEY\n");
      break;
    case 66:
      printf("You pressed the DOWN KEY\n");
      break;
    case 67:
      printf("You pressed the RIGHT KEY\n");
      break;
    case 68:
      printf("You pressed the LEFT KEY\n");
      break;
    default:
      printf("Invalid input!\n");
      break;
  }
}

int main ()
{
  const int numOfQuestions = 3;
  int ansArr[numOfQuestions];
  int cnt = 0;

  for (cnt = 0; cnt < numOfQuestions; cnt++)
  {
    printf("Please press an arrow key: \n");
    ansArr[cnt] = getUserInput();
  }

  for (cnt = 0; cnt < numOfQuestions; cnt++)
  {
    printSelection(ansArr[cnt]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the console output:

```
Please press an arrow key: 
^[[D
Please press an arrow key: 
^[[A
Please press an arrow key: 
^[[C
You pressed the LEFT KEY
You pressed the UP KEY
You pressed the RIGHT KEY
```

---

### Update

What you can do is wait for DLE (Data Link Escape) character. This way you can allow the user to enter multiple inputs. Then you can simply save the last input.

Here is the updated function:

```
int getUserInput()
{
  int c = getchar();
  int retVal = 0;

  while (c != 10) // DLE
  {
    if (c == 27)  // ESC
    {
      c = getchar();
      if (c == 91) // [
      {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == UP || c == DOWN || c == LEFT || c == RIGHT)
        {
          retVal = c;  // This is the last valid (arrow key) input
          c = getchar();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return retVal;
}
```

Here is the sample output:

```
Please press an arrow key: 
^[[C
Please press an arrow key: 
^[[D^[[B^[[A^[[C
Please press an arrow key: 
^[[B^[[B^[[A^[[C^[[D^[[C
You pressed the RIGHT KEY
You pressed the RIGHT KEY
You pressed the RIGHT KEY
```

You need to check for some invalid inputs and do some error-handling but that's the idea.

Hope this helps,

Baris

Comment: Thank you Baris, I have a bit of clue now, but it turns out your code reads the first arrow key that was pressed, but the problem is if I first press left but then change my mind and press right then hit 'enter' it would still then output 'You pressed the LEFT KEY'...How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Thank you for you help! I have learned something new thanks to you :-)

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I was able to help :)

Comment: sorry for asking again, may I ask what if today I want to switch my second question to another question? I know the for loop repeats 3 times in this case...but it asks the same question three times

Comment: by the way, Im running win7 using codeblocks with mingw, I currently have problems reading arrowkey values with getchar, but 224 72 for up arrow key etc. works with getch…

Comment: @JohnnyYeng If you want to ask different questions, you can create a "printQuestion" function which takes an int questionNumber as a parameter. You can call this function within the for loop, and for each iteration you can pass "cnt" into the function. And inside the function, just set-up a switch-case block to handle what to print for different questionNumber.

Comment: If you have problems reading the arrowkeys, I suggest you put some getchar() printf() calls back-to-back to see what values you are getting when you hit an arrow key.

Comment: I knew this technic but it doesnt show anything on my sceen :-(